# Vue.js unexpected token in browser but npm run build with no errors

Tags: vue.js

I'm working with a vue.js project someone else started and I'm putting it on a production server. The `npm run build` compiles with no errors. But when i try to run the project in the browser i get a

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token <
```

Here's the `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>tst-apps-suite</title><base href=/ ><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800" rel=stylesheet><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,400,600,700,800" rel=stylesheet><link href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/static/css/app.d79e04c40fa9145fe427147ef17b4576.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.bfe581b46b720086662f.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.19024fb1db555dd8417b.js></script></body></html>
```

I get that for all 3 `.js` asset files.

Server console output on the request. Looks like the files are getting returned:

```
GET /static/css/app.d79e04c40fa9145fe427147ef17b4576.css 200 1.580 ms - 820
GET /static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js 200 3.095 ms - 820
GET /static/js/app.19024fb1db555dd8417b.js 200 3.157 ms - 820
GET /static/js/vendor.bfe581b46b720086662f.js 200 3.429 ms - 820
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't show you the line where the syntax error is?

Comment: no. i wish it did. when i click the file in console it takes me to the beginning of the index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the URLs of the scripts each on a different tab (or check the network tab of the developer tools), those URLs are probably returning a 404 (or some other error code) and a HTML error page.

So your code tries to parse those HTML error pages as JavaScript code, thus yielding that error.

It gets `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`  because it tries to parse the HTML content (e.g. `<html> ...`) as JavaScript code.

Run the snippet below and see the error at the console.

```html
<script type=text/javascript src=https://stackoverflow.com></script>
Check the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
```

Comment: i updated my question to show the files are getting 200 from server. Also getting same error when i try to open individual JS files in another window.

Comment: That 200 ok from the nodejs console was a false positive. It wasn't really returning the static assets. I fixed the public assets target and it started working.

Comment: @jtlindsey Hi there, I'm having the same issue, could you be more precise on how you fixed it ?

Comment: Great, this solution worked for me. I forgot to use extension `.js` with `<script type="application/javascript" src="{{ asset('app-assets/js/core/app-menu.js') }}"></script>` Opening URL manually from `View Page Source` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to  [the public path in my vue config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) which was looking for a static path like "/mywidget/" and was looking for assets in "/mywidget/dist/1234.js", which was a problem because in my deployment context there was no "mywidget" folder for the built html to find a js file in.

In my case I set the public path to "/" again and it worked.