# Laravel-Vue.js error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I had setup Laravel with Vue.js dependencies like vue-router and vue-axios and also npm install and after just created components into it and run command 'npm run dev' for Laravel mix build successful thereafter I got this console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

My code below:

**blade file code:**

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
          <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
        <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js code**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from './App.vue';
import HomeComponent from './components/HomeComponent.vue';
import CreateComponent from './components/CreateComponent.vue';
import IndexComponent from './components/IndexComponent.vue';
import EditComponent from './components/EditComponent.vue';


Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);






const routes = [
  {
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
      name: 'create',
      path: '/create',
      component: CreateComponent
  },
  {
      name: 'posts',
      path: '/posts',
      component: IndexComponent
  },
  {
      name: 'edit',
      path: '/edit/:id',
      component: EditComponent
  }
];



/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('home-component', require('./components/HomeComponent.vue'));

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

**web.php code**

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('post');
  })->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: The only thing I can see right now is your missing `ExampleComponent`. But I think you already know ;)

Comment: First ExampleComponent I had added in js file and now also added but not working.

Comment: Did you have a look at the generated HTML source in your browser? Try to find the extra `>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js unexpected token in browser but npm run build with no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915530/vue-js-unexpected-token-in-browser-but-npm-run-build-with-no-errors)

Comment: In my case I forgot to use extension `.js` with `<script type="application/javascript" src="{{ asset('app-assets/js/core/app-menu.js') }}"></script>` , first it was `<script type="application/javascript" src="{{ asset('app-assets/js/core/app-menu') }}">`</script> before. Thank You @Unflux opening URL from `View Page Source` solved my problem.